# How to read and display .csv file in vtk window

Tags: visual-studio, vtk

I have a **.csv** file and I need to read it using vtk and display in vtk window itself.How Is it possible?

**EDIT**

Here is my code

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkDelimitedTextReader> reader =
vtkSmartPointer<vtkDelimitedTextReader>::New();
reader->SetFileName("sample.csv");
reader->DetectNumericColumnsOn();
reader->GlobalWarningDisplayOff();
reader->SetFieldDelimiterCharacters(",");
reader->Update();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkTableToPolyData> tabletodata = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTableToPolyData> ::New();
tabletodata->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
tabletodata->Update();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
mapper->SetInputData(tabletodata->GetOutput());
```

Here is my csv file opened in notepad.It has 256 rows and columns

[image]

anyone help please

Comment: Can you specify the content of you csv ? Is it 2/3D model ? or just a table ? How do you want to display it 3d view, spreadsheet ... ?

Comment: its a 3D data.I used "vtkDelimitedTextReader" to read it and converted it into a .vtp file using "vtkDelimitedTextWriter".But i cannot read the generated .vtp file using "vtkXMLPolyDataReader"

Comment: and i want to display it as 3d picture in the vtk render window

Comment: a file written by a vtkXXXWriter is intended to be read only with the associated vtkXXXReader. You cannot do conversion just by using another reader.

Comment: What does your csv look like ? Can you share first lines ?

Answer (score 1):

To read a csv, use the `vtkDelimitedTextReader`.

It ouptuts a `vtkTable`. You can not display it in a render view but you can convert it into a `vtkPolyData` with the `vtkTableToPolyData` filter. https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkTableToPolyData.html

*edit : you have to tell this filter wich CSV column is X, Y and Z*

Then a `vtkPolyData` can be rendered in a 3d view. Example of polydata rendering: https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/Rendering/Cone3/

Comment: Iam getting this error while  updating the vtkTableToPolyData         `Algorithm vtkTableToPolyData(000000000039B5D0) returned failure for request: vtkInformation (000000000038EB50)
  Debug: Off
  Modified Time: 68597
  Reference Count: 1
  Registered Events: (none)
  Request: REQUEST_DATA
  ALGORITHM_AFTER_FORWARD: 1
  FORWARD_DIRECTION: 0
  FROM_OUTPUT_PORT: 0

`

Comment: when i used `GlobalWarningDisplayOff()` the error disppeared but nothing is displayed in the vtkwindow

Comment: Need more info to help (some minimal code to reproduce or at least the lines where you are using the vtkTableToPolyData). Can you update your initial post ?